# Traceroute command "names" in different OS's?

Tags: java, traceroute

I wish to use `"traceroute"` command in my java application. Unfortunately in Windows It is called `"tracert"`. Is there any other "funny" names that I may fell upon in different OS's?

Edit:
I'm interested only in Linux, Windows and Mac distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of, as long as you're only talking about Win/Mac/Linux (and other Unixen in general). VMS or some weird esoteric OS might be different, of course...

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

Mac :  `traceroute`

Windows : `tracert`

Linux : `traceroute`

Answer (score 1):

Here's just a few...

```
Linux   Windows
ls      dir
cp      copy
mv      move
rm      del
cat     type
pwd     chdir
diff    comp
shutdown    reboot
ipconfig    ifconfig
assign  ln
```